# not able to registered user on sql membership on server?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, hosting

I have successfully hosted my mvc website on server.
But I'm not able to registered new user.
I have used following connection string.

`<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Error is 
`A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)`

Using SQL membership tables for create user .
All going good on localhost but after hosting getting error.

Where I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like the aspnetdb.mdf file is not in the Data folder on the host can you confirm the App_Data directory and aspnetdb.mdf file exists on the host?

Comment: yes I did it both `ASPNETDB` and `aspnetdb_log` files are in `App_Data` folder :( any other guess?

Comment: Does your host support using mdf files? The ref in the connection string "DataDirectory" may not be linking to the directory you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

On remote server you need to change your connection string. Please user correct server url/ip and db name

Comment: can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Connection string should be in this format <add name="SiteDBConn" connectionString="Server=IPOfServer;Database=DBname;User ID=userhere;Password=passhere;"/>

Comment: userid password for what? 
as I'm copying my all files only in `httpdocs` folder ?

Comment: username and password of user database user account

Comment: @ashuthinks I hope you have the username and password of database user account :)